# CSS specific rule for sidebar in wordpress on one page

Tags: css, wordpress

Hey I have a wordpress blog, and I need to add some negative margin on the sidebar on the index page, but not on any other page, the trouble is since the sidebar is in "sidebar.php" and the head element is in "header.php" so I can't use inline styles or styles just for that page.

Any ways of achieving this?

I would assume a PHP if statement in the header?

For the moment I've used a style element within the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used wordpress in some time, but from what I remember, there was a specific home/index template... You could wrap the sidebar in a tag and sub-reference that through css.

css:

```
#sidebar-fix #sidebar element {...}
```

html:

```
<div id="sidebar-fix"><?#sidebar include?></div>
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Just tired I expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the is_page function to single out the page you want.  Here is an example and a link.

```
<?php if (is_page('My Page')) { ?>
    <style type="text/css">Your style here</style>
<?php } ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page